# How to pass input From JSP to other JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

First JSP, `currencyConversion.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Currency Conversion</title>
    <style>
label{ display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top:10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Use JSP Declaration tag, JSP Scriplet and JSP Expression
    in application</h1>
    <font style="color:plum; font-family:verdana;"><b>
        Currency Conversion</b></font>
        <form id="currency" action="processCurrency.jsp" method="get">
            <label for="amount">Amount (in RM)</label>
            <input name="amount" id="amount"></br>
            <label for = "currency">Convert to</label>
     <select name="currency" id = "currency"><br/>
        <option value = "1">USD</option>
        <option value = "2">Pound Sterling</option>
                    <option value = "3">Euro</option>
     </select>
     <br />
             <br />
             <input type = "submit" id = "btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
     <input type = "reset" id = "btnReset" value = "Reset"/>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second JSP, `processCurrency.jsp`

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Currency process</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
      String currency=request.getParameter("currency");
      int amount=request.getParameter("amount");
     %>
    <%!
    final double USD=3.92;
    final double STG=5.96;
    final double EURO=4.47;
    double calculateRate(String currency, int amount)
    {
       double currencyChange=0.00f;
        if(currency.equals("1"))
       currencyChange=(double)(amount*USD);
        if(currency.equals("2"))
           currencyChange=(double)(amount*STG);
        if(currency.equals("3"))
            currencyChange=(double)(amount*EURO);
        return currencyChange;
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

I have try using `JSP:param`, but it wont let me pass the amount as it state that different datatype.

```
<%int amount=request.getParameter("amount");%>
```

How to pass the currency and amount from the currencyConversion.jsp into double calculateRate(String currency, int amount) in the processCurrency.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

What you get is a String value, convert it to int.

```
int amount = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("amount"));
```

Comment: what the difference between <%!        %> and <%        %>?

Comment: how can I pass the amount and currency into  double calculateRate(String currency, int amount){ @tak3shi

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
        String currency=request.getParameter("currency");
        double amount=Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("amount"));
        out.println("MYR "+amount+" to");

    final double USD=3.92;
    final double STG=5.96;
    final double EURO=4.47;

       double currencyChange=0.00f;
        if(currency.equals("1")){
       currencyChange=(double)(amount*USD);
        out.println("USD "+currencyChange);}
       else if(currency.equals("2")){
           currencyChange=(double)(amount*STG);
        out.println("Sterling Pound "+currencyChange);}
       else if(currency.equals("3")){
            currencyChange=(double)(amount*EURO);
        out.println("EURO "+currencyChange);}


    %>
```